# Problems with non-blocking select with java.nio

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I've just started using java.nio and probably used it some wrong way so I got a slight problem with it.

I'm trying to write a something like a Port Forwarder that can modify the traffic that passes through it using various additional modules.

Here is how I'm doing it:

1. ConnectionManager - a thread that
   has it's own Selector that is
   registered to OP_ACCEPT on
   ServerSocketChannel. Whenever it
   selects anything - it creates a
   ConnectionProcessor object that
   manages the connection.
2. ConnectionProcessor - a thread
   that opens SocketChannel to
   predefined forward point (where to
   send the packets from the newly
   connected client). Then it opens
   it's own Selector and registers it
   to client's SocketChannel's OP_READ
   and server's SocketChannel's
   OP_READ.

Then the processor goes into infinite loop selecting data from selector and forwarding it appropriately. To determine where to send data it compares SelectionKey.channel() to clientChannel and serverChannel.

Selection in ConnectionProcessor is made with timeout of 5 seconds (select(5000)) - to handle timeouts. When select times out - it tries to read from both channels to get an exception or -1 result.

Now here are my questions/problems:

1. Is it right to use key.cancel()
   after processing the key? Most
   examples I've seen in the internet
   simply remove the key from
   selectedKeys() list. key.cancel()
   seems to be much better approach.
2. Is it right to have several
   selectors that basically use the
   same ServerSocketChannel? Or should I always use single Selector and pass selected keys 
   to appropriate Managers? What I
   mean is that if 3 clients connect
   simultaneously then this is what
   will happen:

   a) Manager creates Processor.
   Processor opens client channel.
   Processor registers it's own
   selector to the client channel. b)
   repetition of (a) c) repetition of
   (a)
3. For some reason, after even one client connects to my forwarder - it won't process 
   messages faster than 5000msec timeout. It starts selecting, locks for 5 seconds, then go 
   to second iteration and fetches me 5-6 messages that I received during previous timeout.
   Should I blame (1), (2), or some other reason?
4. Is there any manual on how this all nio stuff works internally? I'm kind of a person that understands how to use things only after I fully understand the mechanics underneath. Reading API does not help as it is written for people who already know the proper way of using nio.

Thanks for reading my whole question and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: NIO is tedious to get correct. I would recommend [XNIO](http://jboss.org/xnio) or [MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) or insert-NIO-wrapper-library-here to save some headaches and get a more consistent base. One of the "simple" NIO issues is the need to wake-up the select on data-ready for writing (which is different than the channel being write-able). Happy coding.

Comment: Hm... So if I put something to the channel and try to select from it simultaneously it wont send any data until select is completed? That's scary, gonna check out XNIO and MINA. Thanks for advice.

Comment: No, he didn't say that. He is referring to various issues that arise when handling writes, and there are various ways of handling them. The simplest technique is to do all writing inline in the select thread, but even that has its quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Just remove the key from the selected set. Usually this is done via iterator.remove(). If you cancel they key it will never be selected again.
2. It's pointless. You don't need the second selector, or the extra thread either. That's what NIO is for. You can handle it all with the original selector within the original thread.
3. It's probably caused by strange code. Redo it as above and see if it still happens. If so, post some code here.
4. You would need to read the Berkeley Sockets API or a good book such as Stevens, Unix Network Programming, or mine ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, going to try them right away. As for (4) - I didn't mean windows Sockets, I meant the nio part. Like how the selector works, etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about number (2). The extra modifications over the packets could take some long time (like 2-5 seconds), while I want to maintain several clients connected at once. So which way should I do it?

Comment: NIO just uses select() under the hood, to a first approximation. What you say about (2) doesn't change anything. You just select until something happens, then you handle it: OP_READ or OP_ACCEPT.

Comment: @Max So you let the (single) selector itself block -- it can monitor n channels, maintain read/write-able data (on read-able read data, but don't monitor for write-able until data is ready...), wake the selector up as needed, etc. It's ... tedious.

Comment: @EJP Seems like (1) was the problem. Once I changed it to remove iterator it all miraculously started to work. However, could you please explain what exactly does cancel() do? And why should I care that this key is never selected again (I'm already processing it)? Or is it canceling all keys in selector? Thanks.

Comment: Cancel undoes the register step for that channel with that selector. You care because if you cancel you will never select that channel again regardless of what the client does. You won't even get to know about him closing.